# ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare when matching dates in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I apologize in advance for asking such a basic question but I am stumped.

This is a very simple, dummy example. I'm having some issue matching dates in Pandas and I can't figure out why.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'2016-01-01'], 
                   [2,'2016-01-01'],
                   [3,'2016-01-02'],
                   [4,'2016-01-03']],
                   columns=['ID', 'Date'])

df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype('datetime64')
```

Say I want to match row 1 in the above df.
I know beforehand that I want to match ID `1`.
And I know the date I want as well, and as a matter of fact, I'll extract that date directly from row 1 of the df to make it bulletproof.

```
some_id = 1
some_date = df.iloc[1:2]['Date']  # gives 2016-01-01
```

So why doesn't this line work to return me row 1??

```
df[(df['ID']==some_id) & (df['Date'] == some_date)]
```

Instead I get 
`ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare`
which I understand, and makes sense...but leaves me wondering...how else can I compare dates in pandas if I can't compare one to many?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You say:

```
some_date = df.iloc[1:2]['Date']  # gives 2016-01-01
```

but that's *not* what it gives.  It gives a Series with one element, not simply a value -- when you use `[1:2]` as your slice, you don't get a single element, but a container with one element:

```
>>> some_date
1   2016-01-01
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Instead, do

```
>>> some_date = df.iloc[1]['Date']
>>> some_date
Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00')
```

after which

```
>>> df[(df['ID']==some_id) & (df['Date'] == some_date)] 
   ID       Date
0   1 2016-01-01
```

(Note that there are more efficient patterns if you have a lot of `some_id` and `some_date` values to look up, but that's a separate issue.)

Comment: So it all comes down to the difference between `[1:2]` and `1`? These two approaches appear to be syntactically synonymous but apparently not. Why not?

Comment: They're not synonymous even outside of the pandas context.  Try `x = [10, 20, 30]` and then compare `print(x[1:2], type(x[1:2]))` with `print(x[1], type(x[1]))`.  There's a difference between a box with one object in it and just an object.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by DSM, some_date is a series and not a value. When you use boolean masking, and checking if value of a column is equal to some variable or not, we have to make sure that the variable is a value, not a container. One possible way of solving the problem is mentioned by DSM, there is also another way of solving your problem.

```
df[(df['ID']==some_id) & (df['Date'] == some_date.values[0])]
```

We have just replaced the some_date with some_date.values[0]. some_date.values returns an array with one element. We are interested in the value in the container, not the container, so we index it by [0] to get the value.