# Python Pandas - Create DataFrame based on a value from a file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame (df1). something like this:

```
   CUST_KEY   SDATE      QTI
0  1997041501 2016-06-21 2.000000
1  1975122001 2016-07-08 1.000000
2  1978091401 2016-07-01 31.000000
3  1950090501 2016-06-01 2.000000
```

I also have a dataframe I made from an excel file:

```
metadf = pd.read_excel('C:\TEMP\METADATA.xlsx')
metadf1 = metadf[0:1]
eff_from = pd.to_datetime(metadf1['EFF_FROM'], format="%d/%m/%Y")
metadf1.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 4 columns):
EFF_FROM    1 non-null datetime64[ns]
SDATE       1 non-null datetime64[ns]
EDATE       1 non-null datetime64[ns]
NOTES       1 non-null object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](3), object(1)
memory usage: 112.0+ bytes
0   2016-07-01
```

What I'm trying to do is create a new DataFrame from df1, where the SDATE >= EFF_FROM from metadf1.
I don't think a merge is going to work. Can I use eff_from as a variable? It looks like I've created a series in my     eff_from= 
line there (very new to python, bit confused about the myriad types of data there are!)
Many thanks for your help

Comment: What type of your `SDATE` is it datetime object?

Comment: what is the `dytpe` of `SDATE` here? if it's not a datetime then convert it like you've already done for `eff_from`then you should be able to do `df1[df1['SDATE'] >= metadf1['EFF_FROM'][0]]` I think should work, the `[0]` is to get the scalar value from the df

Comment: SDATE is a datetime64 so EdChum's suggestion should work. Is that a line of code on it's own, filtering df1? can i create a new dataset df2 from df1? I'm getting
        ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare
even though both variables are datetime64 type. However, that's when i take out the extra [0]. When I add that there's a Key Error. Apologies, i can't seem to get the code formatting to work in comments!

Comment: I think [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586069/valueerror-series-lengths-must-match-to-compare-when-matching-dates-in-pandas) might help with the ValueError