# How to compare np.datetime64 up to month only?

Tags: python, numpy

I stumbled upon a "problem" while working with my data some time ago, when I started messing with pandas. That problem is that, when you compare `np.datetime64` objects with strings, numpy will fill out the rest of the information to fit datetime with the lowest value possible (01 for months, 01 for days and so on).
The same happens if you call an `np.datetime64` object and specify only up to the month, the rest of the information will still be filled with the lowest possible value:

```
np.datetime('2019-07','M')
>>numpy.datetime64('2019-08')
```

The problem for me is that, many times, my only concern is with what happens between time periods, like months. 
For exemple, if I want to filter every row where payments were made within last month, it would be ideal to use:

```
month = '2019-07'
df[df['pay_day']==month]
```

But when doing something like that, it will compare up to the day and fail for every date that isn't the first day of the month. I have tried transforming datetime to str, slicing and putting it back together, but for filtering purposes it gets messy. Another thing I have tried is:

```
df['pay_day'].days=1
```

The idea was to bring all days to 01, so there would be no problem when comparing and filtering, but it just fills the whole column with `int64` 1's.
Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Is it a typo or is your mask `df[df['pay_day']=month]`, because it should be `df[df['pay_day']==month]`

Comment: Yes it was a typo, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas datetime accessor object [`.dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html)and get corresponding property (`month` here) for comparison.

```
df[df['pay_day'].dt.month == month]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way that works for this problem in specific: if we set all days to 01, there should be no problem, but it is hard do manipulate `np.datetime64`. There is a way, though:

```
df['pay_day'] = df['pay_day'].astype('datetime64[M]')
```

So that all days will be set to 01, and comparison based on month becomes easy. But if there is a need of editing the days to any other value, I guess it's harder, but this works.

I got the idea from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52810147/8424939