# Numpy datetime64 extract month-day

Tags: python, numpy, date

I have the 3d data set and I want to have only month-date i.e numpy.datetime64('05-09').
Any idea how to do that? The original 3d datasets:

```
<xarray.DataArray (time: 153, lat: 281, lon: 481)>
array([[[5839.5454, 5839.581 , 5839.4844, ..., 5865.13  , 5865.8213,
         5865.933 ],
        [5838.614 , 5838.59  , 5838.548 , ..., 5864.121 , 5864.8354,
         5865.13  ],

       
       [[5853.7334, 5854.075 , 5854.291 , ..., 5882.3706, 5882.638 ,
         5882.379 ],
        [5853.297 , 5853.583 , 5853.858 , ..., 5882.602 , 5882.878 ,
         5882.687 ],

        ...,

        [5230.2534, 5230.2534, 5230.2534, ..., 5230.2534, 5230.2534,
         5230.2534]]], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * lon      (lon) float64 -80.0 -79.75 -79.5 -79.25 ... 39.25 39.5 39.75 40.0
  * lat      (lat) float64 20.0 20.25 20.5 20.75 21.0 ... 89.25 89.5 89.75 90.0
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-05-01 2000-05-02 ... 2000-09-30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an option, I can suggest making a data frame from your array. Change the data frame to a string one and then extract the necessary elements. Turn the data into a list.
But, it will be a string format. If you convert it back to datetime64, you will get the other thing.

```
 import numpy
 import pandas as pd

 aaa = [numpy.datetime64('2000-05-01T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2000-05-02T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2000-05-03T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2000-05-04T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2000-05-05T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2000-05-06T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2000-05-07T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2000-05-08T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2000-05-09T00:00:00.000000000')]

 df = pd.DataFrame(aaa, columns=['abc'])
 df['abc'] = df['abc'].astype('str').str[5:10]
 bbb = df['abc'].to_list()
```

Output

```
['05-01', '05-02', '05-03', '05-04', '05-05', '05-06', '05-07', '05-08', '12-01']
```

If you are satisfied with drawing in the library matplotlib. Then in the code I set it to 'formatter' so that only the month and day are displayed on the x-axis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates
import numpy
import pandas as pd

aaa = [numpy.datetime64('2000-05-01T00:00:00.000000000'),
       numpy.datetime64('2000-05-02T00:00:00.000000000'),
       numpy.datetime64('2000-05-03T00:00:00.000000000'),
       numpy.datetime64('2000-05-04T00:00:00.000000000'),
       numpy.datetime64('2000-05-05T00:00:00.000000000'),
       numpy.datetime64('2000-05-06T00:00:00.000000000'),
       numpy.datetime64('2000-05-07T00:00:00.000000000'),
       numpy.datetime64('2000-05-08T00:00:00.000000000'),
       numpy.datetime64('2000-05-09T00:00:00.000000000')]

ttt = [1, 3, 7, 5, 10, 2, 5, 1, 7]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(aaa, ttt)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("%m.%d"))
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If the date is e.g., `2000-12-01...`, this would return `2-01` instead of `12-01`

Comment: The problem is that I need the data in array since I have 3d data. Is there any way to do this without converting it into a dataframe? And I need to plt them afterwards and xarray.plot( requires a date object.

Comment: Variable bbb is not a data frame, it is an array. That is, the dataframe is converted back to an array .to_list()

Comment: Yes it is but in order to plot the data the coordinate(time needs to be numeric or a date object). So even I have the list I cannot plot it:(

Comment: If you convert bbb back to date = np.array(bbb, dtype=np.datetime64), then two zeros are added ['0005-01' '0005-02' '0005-03' '0005-04' '0005-05' '0005-06' '0005-07'
 '0005-08' '0012-01']

Comment: I get an error ValueError: Month out of range in datetime string "05-13":(

Comment: @les2004 And converted to dtype=np.datetime64 will mean the wrong thing 1 month, 1 number, 5 year ('0005-01').

Comment: I see, I guess there is no other solution?

Comment: At least I don't know any others. 1. If only on the x-axis, you can submit string values(if possible). 2. Perhaps there is a parameter in the axis setting to specify only the month and day (in my opinion, in matplotlib, I saw something similar).  What library do you draw with?

Comment: x.array plotting.

Comment: @les2004 Updated the answer, matplotlib library, draws what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot! By data are ed that is why I used xarray.plot. If I try to use matplotlib then I get an error:)

Comment: Print out some of your data in the main message and its type. I think they can be placed in matplotlib. Or everything that you wanted turned out?

Comment: It will be difficult to understand which of these you want to draw. I wash my hands of it, continue with someone else)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply access the [`dt` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57381718/5218354):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


first = np.datetime64('2000-05-01T00:00:00.000000000')
data = [first + np.timedelta64(i, 'D') for i in range(10)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['full'])

df['Y'] = df['full'].dt.year
df['M'] = df['full'].dt.month
df['D'] = df['full'].dt.day
print(df)
#         full     Y  M   D
# 0 2000-05-01  2000  5   1
# 1 2000-05-02  2000  5   2
# 2 2000-05-03  2000  5   3
# 3 2000-05-04  2000  5   4
# 4 2000-05-05  2000  5   5
# 5 2000-05-06  2000  5   6
# 6 2000-05-07  2000  5   7
# 7 2000-05-08  2000  5   8
# 8 2000-05-09  2000  5   9
# 9 2000-05-10  2000  5  10
```